# Android Replace Listview With RecycleView for displaying Simple data

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am learning RecycleView now and just wondering how to display the data in the same way like Listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), mobileArray[i],
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The above coding is just to display the Array in ListView using ArrayAdapter. When clicking on the item, it will Toast that position value.

So the same thing for Recycleview, I saw some examples online that are with very many lines of coding or even separate files. Is Recycleview really need so many lines of coding to display a simple array like this?

```
String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
```

**Anyone can provide a simplest example to Display an Array in RecycleView with  onItemClick then show that position in Toast? OR did I do it wrongly as Recycleview is used to do something more complex or just listview will do for my case?**